# mysql alter to table

Tags: mysql, alter

I drop the mysql alter code below to database via phpmyadmin one by one, it it work fine, is there anyone could help me how to drop it all together at once? Or do you know the the samples of PHP code that may execute it? Just let me know please.

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `title`
varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `user_id`

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `title`
varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `customer_id`;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `date_birtdate` datetime NOT NULL 
 DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AFTER `lastname`;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `security_question` varchar(96) COLLATE utf8_bin 
  NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `fax`;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `security_answer` varchar(96) COLLATE utf8_bin 
  NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `fax`;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `pin_number` text COLLATE utf8_bin AFTER `password`;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin AFTER `bank_number`;

ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `last_active` datetime NOT NULL 
  DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AFTER `date_added`;
```

Comment: You want us to reformat some text for you? How is this not the definition of laziness? You can do it yourself. here's a hint: `str_replace('ALTER TABLE customer', ',', $query)`.

Comment: -1 for not formatting your SQL properly

Comment: I'm not sure MySQL supports schema changes within transactions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `;` at end of each query ;-) then u can put them together as one block. with php you can't do it that easy way.

Comment: Thanks, i did it at previous and get an error, perhaps not all completely ; at the end